# Getting Error in using View and ViewData in .NetCore 2.2 Project --

Tags: asp.net-core, view, controller, asp.net-core-2.2, viewdata

a quick question. I am getting following error when trying to return view from my controller method.

***The name View does not exist in current context***

refer this pic to understand my project structure -- https://pasteboard.co/Jh1AxGy.png

My code is

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using AutoMapper;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using CoreSpeechService.App.Utility;

    public IActionResult ProductInfo(int p_id)
    {
        if(p_id>0)
        {
            var pEntity = pService.GetProductById(p_id);
            if(pEntity!=null)
            {
                ViewData["ProductId"] = pEntity.Id;
                return View(pEntity);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Could not fetch detailes related to this product at the moment. Please try later.");
        }
    }
```

One would have thought I have added all necessary namespaces in controller. Apparently not. I have a hunch it is mostly due to my project structure [the controller and cshtml files]. Proper scaffolding issue? What
should be done?

Suggestions. Thanks

** worth mentioning  -  my controller is inherited from ControllerBase and not Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The name View does not exist in current context

That is because your controller inherits from `ControllerBase`.You could check the source code below,`ControllerBase` does not contain `View()` method by default.`Controller` inherits from `ControllerBase` and add view support:

```
//A base class for an MVC controller with view support.
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
{
    protected Controller();
     
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object that renders a view to the
    //     response.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual ViewResult View();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object by specifying a viewName.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   viewName:
    //     The name or path of the view that is rendered to the response.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual ViewResult View(string viewName);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object by specifying a viewName
    //     and the model to be rendered by the view.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   viewName:
    //     The name or path of the view that is rendered to the response.
    //
    //   model:
    //     The model that is rendered by the view.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, object model);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object by specifying a model to
    //     be rendered by the view.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   model:
    //     The model that is rendered by the view.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult object for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual ViewResult View(object model);       
}
```

From your such scenario,just change `ControllerBase` to `Controller`:

```
public class ProductController : Controller { }
```

Besides,I see your structure contains Razor Pages.When you use `return View(model)`,it would render the razor view with the model data.Be sure you have a razor view named `ProductInfo.cshtml` instead of a razor pages named `ProductInfo.cshtml`.

Comment: Hi @Rena -- yes, I did that already and works fine. Also there was another issue of nomenclature of my folder and hence impacting my namespace, raising ambiguity